# How would you improve this sentence?

Tags: grammar

When I say

> "That dish is very nice. I will make you eat someday."

it strikes me as pretty awkward. Would this be an improvement:

> "That dish is very nice.I will treat with that someday."

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That dish is very good, **I'll make it for you** someday.

Comment: Here.I meant to say. I am not preparing it.I will make him eat.I don't know how to get the  sentence right.

Comment: How will you get someone to ***try it***  or ***taste it*** if you or someone else in your family doesn't make/cook the dish? Do you want to treat someone in a restaurant? You cannot say "I will make you eat it" it sounds as if you are forcing that person to eat it against their will.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. Yes.There is a restaurant/place which makes the same dish.I want to make him eat.I don't know the correct sentence for it.

Comment: Then just tell the person you know a restaurant that makes a great [Dish Name] and you would love to take him/her there someday. (*I know a restaurant that makes a great XXX, would you like to try it one day?*)

Comment: `I want to make him eat.` ..... this just sounds bad .... sounds like you want to twist his arm and shove his face in the plate  ..........this is more relaxed  `That dish is very nice. I would like you to taste it someday.`

Comment: Haha. That was exactly I was thinking of. Thanks @jsotola

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

> That's a great dish. You should try it someday.

Or:

> Great dish, that. Perhaps I should make it for you one of these days.

Or:

> That's one amazing dish. I'll make it for you when you come over one
>   of these days.

Or:

> That's a magnificent dish. You have no idea. I'll have you sample it
>   one of these days.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here.I meant to say. I am not preparing it.I will make him eat.I don't know how to get the sentence right

Comment: @Javasamurai read the suggestions carefully, they are not only talking about making the dish. Ricky has covered two possible situations.